# Stream deployment properties are being locked after a deployment with errors

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

We're using spring cloud dataflow 2.10.3 deployed using helm in a kubernetes cluster.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something were doing wrong but we've seen it happen across all types of streams, custom source/sink/processor and some of the pre-packaged apps.

Essentially, if we create a stream and add a deployment property that is invalid or causes one of the components of the stream to crash, scdf locks the properties. Any deployment properties changed after this point are not used or saved, meaning we can't fix the invalid property.

Quickest way to reproduce:

`sftp | log`

In the freetext deployment properties add something like:

`app.sftp.supplier.rename-remote-files-to=archive.someBadProperty()`

This SpEL is invalid and will cause the sftp app to crash. Undeploy and then after this any changes we make to the properties will not be kept. Ultimately we have to destroy the stream and recreate it.

Has anyone else encountered this? Any workarounds?

**Bonus Question** For the sftp source pre-packaged app, what is a valid SpEL for keeping the original file name and just adding a prefix of `archive/`?

Answer (score 0):

The `app.sftp.supplier.rename-remote-files-to` property is mapped to the `SftpOutboundGateway.setRenameExpression()` where a root object of the evaluation expression is a request `Message` for this gateway as a result of the SFTP message source. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/sftp.html.

If your goal is to definitely rename that consumed remote file to the `archive` directory, then your expression must be like this:

```
'archive/' + headers.file_remoteFile
```

(Probably without white spaces to satisfy SCDF environment...)

Comment: We created this issue in Spring Cloud Dataflow https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/5461. It may not be Dataflow specific but we will start there.